# Passing variables using jquery and ajax php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

i'm following this tutorial, so my issue is:
I have this code here, which are some tables.

```
<tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="edit_tr">

<td class="edit_td">
<span id="first_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $kodi; ?></span>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $kodi; ?>" class="editbox" id="first_input_<?php echo $id; ?>" /&gt;
</td>

<td class="edit_td">
<span id="last_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $vlera; ?></span>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $vlera; ?>" class="editbox" id="last_input_<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</td>

</tr>
```

Now, this is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".edit_tr").click(function()
{
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
$("#first_"+ID).hide();
$("#last_"+ID).hide();
$("#first_input_"+ID).show();
$("#last_input_"+ID).show();
}).change(function()
{
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
var kodi=$("#first_input_"+ID).val();
var vlera=$("#last_input_"+ID).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&kodi='+kodi+'&vlera='+vlera;
$("#first_"+ID).html('<img src="load.gif" />'); // Loading image

if(first.length>0&& last.length>0)
{

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "table_edit_ajax.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#first_"+ID).html(first);
$("#last_"+ID).html(last);
```

I'm not passing variables right maybe..because it won't save them, the query won't excecute.
Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: NO ERROR, IT JUST WON'T UPDATE THE VALUES

Comment: Can you use something like Firebug? It will show you the ajax request and then you can see what are you passing via post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way in jQuery to pass your form fields in ajax is by using [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
data: $("form").serialize();
```

An additional problem is that you are using two variables, `first` and `last` but you are not defining them anywhere.

Comment: Well, i can't modify this one correctly, it's harder for me to do something like this..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(function() { // This makes the same than $(document).ready();
    $(".edit_tr").each(function() { // Instead of assign the click event, we loop through each element
        var $element = $(this);
        var id = this.id;
        var $first = $('#first_' + id);
        var $last = $('#last_' + id);
        var $firstInput = $('#first_input_' + id);
        var $lastInput = $('#last_input_' + id);
        $element.click(function() {
            $first.hide();$last.hide();
            $firstInput.show();$lastInput.show();
        }).change(function() {
            $first.html('<img src="load.gif" />');
            // Here you have an if, but those elements are not defined in the script...
            // if (first.length > 0 && last.length > 0) {
            $.post("table_edit_ajax.php", {
                id : id,
                kodi : $firstInput.val(),
                vlera : $lastInput.val()
            }, function(html) {
                // Here again the two vars not defined
                //$first.html(first);
                //$last.html(last);
            });
            // }
        });
    });
});
```